# Unable to add bootstrap in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

Hi I am using using Angular 5 and I am trying to import bootstrap in my code but unable to do so. I have installed bootstrap using:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

I have also add the css file to the .angular-cli.json as:

```
"styles": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "styles.css"
],
```

But when I inspect my code in google chrome what I get is this,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>MyFirstApp</title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   </head>
   <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

There is no styles for bootstrap in the header section. Please help me. I am stuck

Comment: Stop the application and start it again on terminal. Changes in `.angular-cli.json` will be applied after restarting process.

Comment: You don't have to import both bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.css.
bootstrap.min.css is just the minified version of bootstrap.css.
Although i'm aware that's not going to solve your problem...

Comment: i have done both because the minified version is also not working as you can see up in the view source above. i have started the application multiple times.

Comment: @AnkitKathait try removing bootstraps css entry in /angular-cli.json and add 
`@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` to style.scss in our angular project

Comment: in case you are not using .scss then you should actually try. Its awesome !

Comment: @AnkitKathait You are doing it in the right way by adding it in the styles sections of the `.angular-cli.json` file. The css will be compiled in a `styles.bundle.css`, e.g. `<link href="styles.c8974d3e9e1ca3ccac00.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` and will be added in the head section. build your application and inspect this bundle to see if bootstrap is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",

use same like this

Answer (score 1):

Try This, add your style `bootstrap.min.css` to `style.css`

`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`

Answer (score 0):

Add your style `bootstrap.min.css` to `style.css` main:

```
@import "../src/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```